# std::bind yields compilation error in libstdc++

Tags: c++, c++11, libstdc++

The following piece of code compiles without problems:

```
void dimse_pm::f()
{
       ul.inject(upperlayer::TYPE::A_ASSOCIATE_RQ,
           [=](upperlayer::scx* sc, std::unique_ptr<upperlayer::property> rq) { 
               associate(sc, std::move(rq)); 
            } 
       );
}
```

However, the following code using std::bind fails to compile.

```
void dimse_pm::f()
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    ul.inject(upperlayer::TYPE::A_ASSOCIATE_RQ,
         std::bind(&dimse_pm::associate, this, _1));
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/include/g++-v4/functional:1925:2: error: no matching function for call to     object of type 'std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (dimse_pm::*)(upperlayer::scx *, std::unique_ptr<upperlayer::property,
  std::default_delete<upperlayer::property> >)> (dimse_pm *, std::_Placeholder<1>)>'
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/include/g++-v4/functional:2298:33: note: in instantiation of member function  'std::_Function_handler<void (upperlayer::scx *, std::unique_ptr<upperlayer::property,
  std::default_delete<upperlayer::property> >), std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (dimse_pm::*)(upperlayer::scx *,  std::unique_ptr<upperlayer::property, std::default_delete<upperlayer::property> >)>
  (dimse_pm *, std::_Placeholder<1>)> >::_M_invoke' requested here
        _M_invoker = &_My_handler::_M_invoke;
                                   ^
dimse_pm.cpp:25:14: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::function<void (upperlayer::scx *, std::unique_ptr<upperlayer::property, std::default_delete<upperlayer::property>
  >)>::function<std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (dimse_pm::*)(upperlayer::scx *, std::unique_ptr<upperlayer::property, std::default_delete<upperlayer::property> >)> (dimse_pm *, std::_Placeholder<1>)> >' requested here
         std::bind(&dimse_pm::associate, this, _1));
         ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/include/g++-v4/functional:1211:2: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Args = <upperlayer::scx *, std::unique_ptr<upperlayer::property,
  std::default_delete<upperlayer::property> >>]: no matching function for call to object of type 'std::_Mem_fn<void (dimse_pm::*)(upperlayer::scx *, std::unique_ptr<upperlayer::property,
  std::default_delete<upperlayer::property> >)>'
    operator()(_Args&&... __args)
    ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/include/g++-v4/functional:1225:2: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Args = <upperlayer::scx *, std::unique_ptr<upperlayer::property,
  std::default_delete<upperlayer::property> >>]: no matching function for call to object of type 'const std::_Mem_fn<void (dimse_pm::*)(upperlayer::scx *, std::unique_ptr<upperlayer::property,
  std::default_delete<upperlayer::property> >)>'
    operator()(_Args&&... __args) const
    ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/include/g++-v4/functional:1239:2: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Args = <upperlayer::scx *, std::unique_ptr<upperlayer::property,
  std::default_delete<upperlayer::property> >>]: no matching function for call to object of type 'volatile std::_Mem_fn<void (dimse_pm::*)(upperlayer::scx *, std::unique_ptr<upperlayer::property,
  std::default_delete<upperlayer::property> >)>'
    operator()(_Args&&... __args) volatile
    ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/include/g++-v4/functional:1253:2: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Args = <upperlayer::scx *, std::unique_ptr<upperlayer::property,
  std::default_delete<upperlayer::property> >>]: no matching function for call to object of type 'const volatile std::_Mem_fn<void (dimse_pm::*)(upperlayer::scx *, std::unique_ptr<upperlayer::property,
  std::default_delete<upperlayer::property> >)>'
    operator()(_Args&&... __args) const volatile
```

`associate` is a member function of `dimse_pm` and not overloaded. The object `ul` on which the inject function is called, stores `std::function<void(scx*, std::unique_ptr<property>)>`. I want to get rid of the this-pointer. This error happens with both clang 3.5 and gcc 4.7.3.

Comment: `associate` is not overloaded, but you are calling it with a different number of arguments. Did you forget `_2`?

Comment: The inject function stores `std::function<void(scx*, std::unique_ptr<property>)>` in the `ul` object. Therefore I want to get rid of the implicit this pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[=](upperlayer::scx* sc, std::unique_ptr<upperlayer::property> rq) { 
     associate(sc, std::move(rq)); 
}
```

This lambda function object calls `associate` with two arguments (`upperlayer::scx*` and `std::unique_ptr<upperlayer::property>&&`) plus the `this` pointer.

```
std::bind(&dimse_pm::associate, this, _1)
```

This bind expression object calls `associate` with *one argument* plus the `this` pointer, which fails because `associate` expects two arguments plus the `this` pointer.

What you want is this:

```
std::bind(&dimse_pm::associate, this, _1, _2)
```

`this, _1, _2` means that `this` will be captured and forwarded as the implicit `this` argument to `associate`, the first argument to the bind expression's call operator will be forwarded as the first explicit argument to `associate` and the second argument to the bind expression's call operator will be forwarded as the second explicit argument to `associate`.

Comment: Thanks. I had a fundamental fallacy in how std::bind works. It's clear now.